# Password in Java through the use of regexes

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I'm trying to make a password by using regexes, and I don't understand why my code doesn't work :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class test {

 public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a password please.");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

    int x;
    String redex = "(^[0-9]+$)";
    String redexx = "(^[A-Z]+$)";

    boolean hasSpace = false;
    boolean hasUpperCase = false;
        boolean hasLetter = false;
        boolean hasDigit = false; // we set four booleans to be able to bring up individual error messages.

    if (password.length() > 8){
        hasLetter = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your password needs to be at least 8 characters long.");                        

        if (password.matches(redexx)) { // we check to see if the password has at least an upper case letter, one or more digits and a space using regular expressions
            hasUpperCase = true;

        } if (password.matches(redexx)) { 
            hasDigit = true; 

        } if (password.indexOf(' ') == 1) {
            hasSpace = true; }

    } if (hasLetter && hasDigit && hasUpperCase && !hasSpace) {
        System.out.println("Your password is strong."); 
    } if (!hasDigit) {      
                System.out.println("You need to put numbers in your password."); 
    } if (!hasUpperCase) {
        System.out.println("You need to use an upper case letter in your password."); 
    } if (hasSpace) {
                    System.out.println("You need to delete any spaces in your password."); 
        } // if we use if statements (and not any "else" or "else if", we get to show all the possible error messages.
    }
}
```

After correcting "regex" and "regexx" and after compiling, when I enter a perfectly applicable password, it still brings up that the password needs an uppercase and that it needs a digit too

Comment: Do you mean regex?

Comment: do you understand why these lines don't compile? String redex = (^[0-9]+$);
    String redexx = (^[A-Z]+$);

Comment: `password.length() > 8` means the password has to be at least 9 characters to pass that test, not 8 as you write 3 lines later.

Comment: Questions that state "my code doesn't work" must inlcude reason why it doesn't work, as well as any errors that occur, inlcuding compilation errors (if the not-working code doesn't compile).

Comment: Also, your code doesn't go to else in case when the password is more than 8 characters long. Seems like you misplaced the statements or the brackets.

Comment: You could just use a single regex and return a named group based on the match and use a switch statement to compare the group's name to each case to return an appropriate value: `^(?:(?<tooShort>.{0,7})|(?<containsSpace>.* .*)|(?<noDigit>\D*)|(?<noUppercase>[^\v\p{Lu}]*)|(?<noLowercase>[^\v\p{Ll}]*)|(?<valid>.{8,}))$`. [See this in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ipWVlJ/1). Note the first entry is the only valid password, all others are not valid to your specifications. This might not be the best answer, but it does solve the issue at hand with minimal code.

Comment: logical thinking is more important than trying technical advanced things. if (password.matches(redexx)) { // we check to see if the password has at least an upper case letter, one or more digits and a space using regular expressions
            hasUpperCase = true;

        } if (password.matches(redexx)) { 
            hasDigit = true; 

        } can you think of a single situation in which the first if would return true, and the second false (or vice versa) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a password please.");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        boolean validLength = password.length() >= 8;
        boolean hasLetter = password.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*");
        boolean hasDigit = password.matches(".*\\d.*");
        boolean hasSpace = password.matches(".*\\s.*");

        if (!validLength)
            System.out.println("The password must be at least 8 characters long.");
        else if (!hasLetter)
            System.out.println("The password must contain at least one letter.");
        else if (!hasDigit)
            System.out.println("The password must contain at least one digit.");
        else if (hasSpace)
            System.out.println("The password must not contain spaces.");
        else
            System.out.println("Your password is strong.");
    }
}
```

Other than the errors mentioned in the comments of your question, you also use incorrect regexes. Read [Java regular expression constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for information on how to use regexes in Java.

Also, space characters actually make passwords stronger, so I would suggest to allow the user to enter space characters. In the demonstrating code of my answer though the user is not allowed to enter space characters, because that was your request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you're not putting the "regexes" in quotation marks. They're strings.

**So try:**

```
String redex = "(^[0-9]+$)";
String redexx = "(^[A-Z]+$)";
```